# Unexpected error in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to form a DataFrame from after applying some constraints through an 'if' statement. I am given the US census of 2010 from which I am trying to find the counties and their respective states that fulfill the conditions. Here I have found the Index by adding regions with value 1 and 2.

STNAME= name of state, CTYNAME= name of county

```
def answer_eight():
   index1=census_df.index[pd.Index(census_df['REGION']).get_loc(1)]
   index2=census_df.index[pd.Index(census_df['REGION']).get_loc(2)]
   index=index1.append(index2)
   new_df=[]
   for i in index:
       if census_df['CTYNAME'][i][:10]=='Washington' and census_df['POPESTIMATE2015'][i]>census_df['POPESTIMATE2014'][i]:
           new_df=pd.DataFrame({'STNAME': pd.Series([census_df['STNAME'][i]], index=[i]),
                             'CTYNAME': pd.Series([census_df['CTYNAME'][i]], index=[i])})
   return new_df

answer_eight()
```

However I am only getting the last index satisfying the conditions in the dataframe whereas there should be 4 rows more as written below-

```
         CTYNAME             STNAME
3163    Washington County   Wisconsin
```

​
Could someone advise what mistake am I making and how to rectify it to get all the desired rows?

Thanks

Comment: You have a better chance of getting an answer here if you post your_df.head() and expected output

Comment: @A-Za-z thanks for the advice, will keep in mind the next time. In this particular case I do not know the correct output, just the dimensions of the output.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Find all rows in REGION 1 and 2 where CTYNAME begins with 'Washington' and POPESTIMATE2015>POPESTIMATE2014?

Comment: Interestingly enough, other people seem to have trouble with the [exact same assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42227438/valueerror-must-pass-dataframe-with-boolean-values-only) (homework?) so I'm hesitating to post an answer.

Comment: @acidtobi yeah that is exactly what I want to do and keep the original indices in the final dataframe. Its an assignment from a MOOC. You can point me in the right direction if not post an answer :)

Comment: You completely replace your `new_df` in every iteration of your loop. This is the reason why there is only one row (the one of the last iteration) in your result list.