# how to preserve original indexes in the new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
def answer_eight():
    templist = list()
    for county, region, p15, p14, ste, cty in zip(census_df.CTYNAME,
                                        census_df.REGION,
                                        census_df.POPESTIMATE2015,
                                        census_df.POPESTIMATE2014,
                                        census_df.STNAME,
                                        census_df.CTYNAME):
        # print(county)
        if region == 1 or region == 2:
            if county.startswith('Washington'):
                if p15 > p14:
                    templist.append((ste, cty))
    labels = ['STNAME', 'CTYNAME']
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(templist, columns=labels)
    return df

         STNAME            CTYNAME
0          Iowa  Washington County
1     Minnesota  Washington County
2  Pennsylvania  Washington County
3  Rhode Island  Washington County
4     Wisconsin  Washington County
```

All these CTYNAME has different indexes in the original census_df. How could I transfer them over to the new DF so the answer looks like:

```
         STNAME            CTYNAME
12          Iowa  Washington County
222     Minnesota  Washington County
400  Pennsylvania  Washington County
2900  Rhode Island  Washington County
2999     Wisconsin  Washington County
```

Comment: It seems you need `df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(templist, columns=labels, index=census_df.index)`

Comment: <code>ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 5), indices imply (2, 3193)</code> produces: ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 5), indices imply (2, 3193)

Comment: It seems you need [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42227438/2901002)

Comment: I have seen this thread but it doesn't work for me either:

    raise AttributeError("Can only use .str accessor with string "
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd include the index with the other things your are zipping

```
def answer_eight():
    templist = list()
    index = list()
    zipped = zip(
        census_df.CTYNAME,
        census_df.REGION,
        census_df.POPESTIMATE2015,
        census_df.POPESTIMATE2014,
        census_df.STNAME,
        census_df.CTYNAME,
        census_df.index
    )        
    for county, region, p15, p14, ste, cty, idx in zipped:
        # print(county)
        if region == 1 or region == 2:
            if county.startswith('Washington'):
                if p15 > p14:
                    templist.append((ste, cty))
                    index.append(idx)
    labels = ['STNAME', 'CTYNAME']
    df = pd.DataFrame(templist, index, labels)
    return df.rename_axis(census_df.index.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Before you start filtering, you can assign the original index to a column with:

```
census_df['original index'] = census_df.index
```

Then just treat it like one of the other columns you're selecting from.

Comment: thanks, I implemented __census_df['original index'] = census_df.index__ before filtering but it doesn't change the outcome. If I add the index = census_df['original index'] to the new FD creation it returns:

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 5), indices imply (2, 3193)

Comment: when did you get that error? when you change `                    `templist.append((ste, cty))` to `templist.append((ste, cty, original_index_column))`?

Comment: if I do this I got the right results but how can I use the last value as an index? http://prntscr.com/f4bnq3

Comment: `your_data_frame_name.reset_index('original_index_column')`

Comment: `print([k[2] for k in templist])` produces `[896, 1419, 2345, 2355, 3163]`   but when I use it in the reset_idnex statement it returns the same results:   `df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(templist)` `df.reset_index([k[2] for k in templist])`